# Cant find element by xpath to select

Tags: java, selenium, selenium-webdriver, xpath

Hi im having serious issues trying to locate this element using an xpath:

```
class="accountSettingsTextBase_1u09j40-o_O-accountSettingsItemText_10y8axf" aria-current="false" href="/account/signin">Log In
```

I've tried:

```
"//*[contains(text(),'Log In')]"
```

and also the actual xpath:

```
//*[@id='root']/div/header/div[3]/nav/ul/li[1]/a
```

as well as link text which still won't work, any ideas??

The anchor tags are missing from the HTML by the way, as it was just showing "Log In" with them added in

Full HTML:
[Full HTML](https://i.stack.imgur.com/5OaHk.png)

Comment: can we have the full html for that element?

Comment: Added to main question

Comment: Could you please check whether the element is available inside the iframe?

Comment: u can directly go to ur instead of clicking it by driver.get("href link")

Comment: How do i check if its in the iframe? oddly when i check if element is clickable its finding it, but when i actually want to click it im getting org.openqa.selenium.WebDriverException: unknown error:

Comment: add the explicit wait with condition as visibilityOfElementLocated and then check

Answer (score 2, accepted):

Possible xpaths :

```
//a[@href='/account/signin']
```

OR

```
//a[contains(.,'Log In')]
```

OR

Try using Css selector :

```
a[class^='accountSettingsTextBase_' ][class*='accountSettingsItemText']
```

Answer (score 0):

```
//[contains(text(),'Log In')]
```

You're missing something:

```
//*[contains(text(),'Log In')]
```

Comment: The format im using is //*[contains(text(),'Log In')]

Answer (score 0):

Why don't you use

```
driver.findElement(By.linkText("Log In"))
```

or

```
driver.findElement(By.partialLinkText("Log In"))
```

since the element is an `anchor` tag?

Answer (score 0):

Please add the explicit wait and then check

```
WebDriverWait wait=new WebDriverWait(driver,20);
wait.until(ExpectedConditions.visibilityOfElementLocated(By.xpath("//*[contains(text(),'Log In')]")));
driver.findElement(By.xpath("//*[contains(text(),'Log In')]")).click();
```